# What does the symbol "::=" mean in specifications?

Tags: specifications

I'm reading the [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-well-formed), and I've come across this symbol, lovingly scattered many times through out the document:

::=

Please could you tell me what it means, thanks.

Comment: Read section 6 of the document to which you link.

Comment: It’s [Backus–Naur form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus–Naur_Form).

Comment: @Physiks lover Can you check if my answer is correct?

Answer (score 1):

The [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-well-formed) states

> The formal grammar of XML is given in this specification using a simple Extended Backus-Naur Form (EBNF) notation. Each rule in the grammar defines one symbol, in the form

```
symbol ::= expression
```